How to deal with intermittent NUTS Sampler stuck in simple inverse problem?
Given a model, I am trying to infer the parameters and quantify the uncertainty of the estimation using NUTS from the blackjax python package. I have multiple input dataset and try to estimate the posterior. This works for some using the automatic tuning offered by blackjax. Yet for others even with manual tuning, the NUTS Sampler runs into points not the maximum likelihood, where the sampler gets stuck. The posteriors and trace look as follows


The issue seems to be the lower bound at >=0 from the prior as the pressure apriori should be positive.
No the NUTS Sampler seems to get stuck resulting in the edge artifact. The point in question represents a model simplification of the underlying ODE. Other than hard priors and potential additional conditions in the model (if statement identifying the simplification), is there a natural way to salvage these posteriors? Can I mathematically sound exclude the condition post-hoc and still attain a valid uncertainty quantification?
Thank you in advance.

can you parameterize that positive parameter on the log-scale?

Hi, I have tried this and a combination of transforming parameters and converting all to log scale. The problem simply shifts from one dimension to the next, It reduces though with regard to the number of datasets  The hard limits of positive number result in an issue around 0 in multiple dimensions. As far as I can tell with Sequential Monte Carlo, the issues gets shifted to particle degeneration.
